# ¿como se puede ingresar dos variables en un mismo input?

Tags: python

en python se puede hacer:
edad, nombre = 19, Alan

me gustaria saber la manera en la que se puede hacer pero con un input.

yo crei que podria ser algo asi:
edad, nombre = input(“inserta tu edad y nombre:”)
print(nombre)
consola:
inserta tu edad y nombre: 19, Alan
Alan

pero al parecer no se puede hacer eso ya que no esta permitido. Ayuda.

Comment: `edad, nombre = input(“inserta tu edad y nombre (separados por comas):”).split(",")`

Answer (score 2):

La función `input` está definida así:

**input([prompt])**

> Si el argumento prompt está presente, se escribe a la salida estándar
> sin una nueva línea a continuación. La función lee entonces una línea
> de la entrada, la convierte en una cadena (eliminando la nueva línea),
> y retorna eso. Cuando se lee EOF, se lanza una excepción EOFError.

La función es bien simple, como se puede apreciar.

La forma normal de ingresar datos es uno a la vez. Si necesitas dos datos que van amarrados (fecha y hora), puedes ingresarlos separandolos con algún caracter adecuado, por ejemplo espacios, y luego haciendo `split()`.

#### Ejemplo

Queremos ingresar nombre y edad. El nombre tiene varias partes, y la edad siempre va al último.

Luego de ingresar nombre-edad como string, lo dividimos en sus componentes (con `split()`). La última parte tiene que ser la edad, y los anteriores, las partes del nombre. El nombre completo lo reconstruyo usando `join()` sobre esas partes.

```
def entra_persona():
    ingreso = input("Ingrese nombre y edad: ")
    partes = ingreso.split()
    edad = partes.pop()
    nombre = ' '.join(partes)
    return nombre, edad
```

Claro que falta agregar las validaciones respecto a la cantidad y tipo de datos (nombre no vacio, edad numérica, etc.)

#### Demo

```
nombre, edad = entra_persona()
print(f"Nombre: {nombre}")
print(f"Edad: {edad}")
```

produce:

```
Ingrese nombre y edad: Jose Alberto Perez 50
Nombre: Jose Alberto Perez
Edad: 50

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

También se pueden ingresar los datos separados por espacio:

```
venta1, venta2, venta3 = input("Escribe las 3 ventas del mes, separadas por un espacio: ").split(" ")
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).